# Dominant mode in rectangular waveguide

Tags: electromagnetism, waveguide

for a standard rectangular wave guide, which a > b (horizontal dimension > vertical dimension), the dominant mode is supposed to be TE10/TM10 mode.

If we flip the direction, make b > a (vertical dimension > horizontal dimension), does this make dominant mode become TE01/TM01?

the definition of dominant mode states that dominant mode is the mode with lowest propagation resistance. Therefore the dominant mode should follow whichever side larger?